# FATAL EXCEPTION MAIN - App crashes on startup

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I run my app I get this error, how should I fix this error, any ideas will be appreciated.

```
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.my_autrui/com.example.my_autrui.Login}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #64: Error inflating class com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2356)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5195)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #64: Error inflating class com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:282)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at com.example.my_autrui.Login.onCreate(Login.java:26)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     ... 11 more
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.widget.LoginButton" on path: /data/app/com.example.my_autrui-1.apk
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
03-11 18:15:35.795: E/AndroidRuntime(5588):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
```

Comment: take a look at this: `ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.widget.LoginButton" on path: `

Comment: This deserves a "Hello world" example as an answer... How about you show your code?

Comment: which all files do you want me to post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the log, it seems LoginButton class is not available which is supposed to be under package com.facebook.widget:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.facebook.widget.LoginButton" on path:
>   /data/app/com.example.my_autrui-1.apk

Are you using a third party library?  You need to add that as a dependency and make sure that while exporting the library is packaged as well.

For adding dependency on a third party, right click on the project and select **Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries** Tab.
To check if the libraries are getting exported, in the same window check **Order and Export** tab.  Make sure the **Android Private Libraries** are added and selected to be exported.

Comment: Actually I just removed the Facebook button code and the application started to work. But never the less, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the package name of the button.

Check the comments here:

[Error inflating class com.facebook.widget.LoginButton with Facebook SDK 4.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29735572/error-inflating-class-com-facebook-widget-loginbutton-with-facebook-sdk-4-0-1/32405244#32405244)